# Filled pictureBox as many time as there are lines in my csv

Tags: vb.net, text-parsing

I try to create a design similar to a mobile Image gallery.

And I have a problem with using TextFieldParser, I tried to reproduce what I understand from the documentation but at the moment when I want to fill my pictureBox with the path of an image an outOfMemoryEception occured...

I tried to prob my code, as far as I know my picturesBox can be created, I can pull into it an image if i give it a path... But "currentRow" doesn't work at all...

```cpp
    Private Sub createAndFillPb()

        ''The path seems to be okay since it doesn't give me an error anymore
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("..\..\Image\csvPic.csv")

            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")

            Dim currentRow As String()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                    ''I want to create as many boxes as there are lines
                    pic(cptPositionGalery) = New PictureBox
                        pic(cptPositionGalery).Width = 150
                        pic(cptPositionGalery).Height = 200
                        pic(cptPositionGalery).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                        pic(cptPositionGalery).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage

                    flpImage.Controls.Add(pic(cptPositionGalery))

                    ''Here's the one giving me such trouble
                    pic(cptPositionGalery).Image = Image.FromFile("currentRow")
                    cptPositionGalerie += 1

                Catch ex As _
                    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &"is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try

            End While
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @41686d6564 Right now, just 4 line delimited by a coma, but I didn't touch anything in my excel so maybe this is the fault of all the null lines ? I'm ashamed but I don't really now how to use the debogger and with that using the solution from your link... But I'm trying right now

Comment: [ReadFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields?view=net-5.0) returns an ARRAY.  What column is the filename name for each row?  To get the filename from the first column, you'd use `currentRow(0)`, for example.  What is `pic` declared as?  I'd expect that to be a `List(Of PictureBox)`, then ADD a dynamic pictureBox with `pic.Add(somePictureBoxVariableDynamicallyCreated)`.

Comment: Project > Properties > Compile tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".  You don't prefer it when creating a lot of bitmaps.  A ListView with resized bitmaps tends to be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I will try on my next Form your technique Hans. The problem as been solved by telling to "currentRow" the column as you say Idle_Mind. You save me a lot of time thanks.